# How to call forms from another class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to call a chart from another class. The code of the chart is this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        chart1.Series["S1"].Points.AddXY(0, 0, 10);
        chart1.Series["S1"].Points.AddXY(0, 0, 10);

    }

}
```

and I want to call this chart from another different class, I tried that:

```
Form1 chart1 = new Form1();
chart1.Show();
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what is the problem? It seems to me that you already provided the answer to your question...

Comment: You created a new copy of the form called chart1 and you want to access the chart1 control off that form.  Try:  chart1.chart1 to get the chart1 object off the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For access forms class and controls from another class, there are simple and more secure methods([link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/42be5e1a-e25b-429a-bf8b-4363034f7930/trying-to-access-form-class-and-controls-from-another-class?forum=winforms)) to do what you want :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        chart1.Series["S1"].Points.AddXY(0, 0, 10);
        chart1.Series["S1"].Points.AddXY(0, 0, 10);

    }

}


    Form chart1 = (Form)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
    //do here what you want
```

Comment: I already did, but the following message appears:  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to access a specific Form1. Not a new one. You can give a reference to it to the other class or make a reference to it static. For example create a field in Form1 like this:

```
public static Form1 Chart;
```

and in the constructor do `Chart = this;` Then you can access it anywhere with `Form1.Chart`.